# On-screen fonts appear tiny on OpenBSD 5.5

Tags: x11, fonts, openbsd, fvwm

I chose the default installation of OpenBSD 5.5. My monitor's brand is Samsung 27-inch 850 series LED. It's in full high-definition, 1920x1080.

After I type my login username and password, I am presented with a window and whatever I type into it appears tiny, that is, the on-screen fonts are too small for me to read.

How do I make the on-screen fonts and icons on the desktop larger for me to see clearly? (I believe the default window manager is FVWM)

Comment: Please confirm that the window manager is indeed FVWM. Open a terminal and run `ps -x`.

Comment: @user66229 You may try to change X server's dpi, like `xrandr --dpi 96` or bigger (e.g. 120)

Comment: @Gilles: I did as told and here are the results: `/usr/X11R6/bin/fvwm` `/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fvwm/FvwmPager 7 4 /usr/X11R6/lib/`

Comment: @nssnd: What's the exact command I should type please? Is it `sudo xrandr --dpi 96`? What's the default dpi when I chose the default installation of OpenBSD? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user66229 I'm not sure, try `sudo xrandr --dpi 120` and reboot. By default it may be 96.